# cbind usage returns unexpected results

Tags: r, cbind

I have a tibble abc and a tibble def.

abc

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Category, Measure [1]
  Category Measure     Date          Value
  <chr>    <chr>       <date>        <dbl>
1 Pickles  Gross Sales 2016-01-03 6518758.
2 Pickles  Gross Sales 2016-01-10 5640691.
3 Pickles  Gross Sales 2016-01-17 5450121.
4 Pickles  Gross Sales 2016-01-24 5726041.
```

def

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
        all       pb
      <dbl>    <dbl>
1 25992010. 4836410.
2 25769111. 4692100.
3 25612548. 4555298.
4 23869990. 4180362.
```

I want to cbind abc and def to get a tibble with 6 columns.

But when I do cbind(abc,def) I get the below. I am not sure why. Can someone help?

```
       abc         def      
Category Character,4 Numeric,4
Measure  Character,4 Numeric,4
Date     Numeric,4   Numeric,4
Value    Numeric,4   Numeric,4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the structure, one of them is grouped with group attributes so we if we `ungroup` or convert to `data.frame` (`as.data.frame` - removes the attributes), `cbind` would work

```
library(dplyr)
abc %>%
   ungroup %>%
   cbind(def)
```

---

It can be reproduced with `mtcars`

```
cbind(as_tibble(head(mtcars[1:4], 3)) %>% 
       group_by(cyl), 
       as_tibble(head(mtcars[5:7], 3)))
#     [,1]      [,2]     
#mpg  Numeric,3 Numeric,3
#cyl  Numeric,3 Numeric,3
#disp Numeric,3 Numeric,3
#hp   Numeric,3 Numeric,3
```

Without group attributes

```
cbind(as_tibble(head(mtcars[1:4], 3)), as_tibble(head(mtcars[5:7], 3)))
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61
```

---

Also, by checking the `methods` for `cbind`

```
methods("cbind")
#[1] cbind.data.frame  cbind.grouped_df* cbind.ts*
```

when there is a `grouped_df`, it automatically calls the `cbind.grouped_df` instead of `cbind.data.frame`.  If we explicitly specify `cbind.data.frame`, it should work

```
cbind.data.frame(as_tibble(head(mtcars[1:4], 3)) %>% 
       group_by(cyl), 
        as_tibble(head(mtcars[5:7], 3)))
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61
```

NOTE: The OP's question was about the behavior with `cbind` and this answers the cause of it

Comment: Thank you. How did you know it was grouped? Is there any function call to know whether a data frame is grouped?

Comment: @user2371765 it is already showed in your post `# Groups:   Category, Measure [1]`

Answer (score 4):

```r
new_tibble <- bind_cols(abc,def)
```